# Delete file in zip subdirectory with spaces in name using script

Tags: bash, zip, pipe, subdirectory, delete-file

I want to write a bash script that deletes certain files from within a zip archive without me knowing the exact location.

I have come this far:

```
for file in *.cbz
do
  zip -sf "$file" | grep banner | sed 's/^ *//g' | { while read p; do  zip -d $file ${p// /\\ } ; done }
done
```

My thinking behind this:

```
zip -sf "$file"
```

gives me all the files in the archive

```
| grep banner
```

This gets me only the lines I am interested in.

```
| sed 's/^ *//g'
```

I pipe the rest sed to get rid of leading spaces

```
| { while read p; do  zip -d $file ${p// /\\ } ; done }
```

The remaining lines get piped here to do a zip delete on the archive with the scraped path+filename. The ${p// /\ } should escape spaces, because simply using $p will cause zip to interepred a name with spaces as a list of files.

However, so do escaped spaces, so I guess the real question is how do delete a file from a zip archive if it's filename contains spaces.

Comment: Quoted filename should suffice: e.g. `zip -d test.zip "file name.txt"` would delete the file `file name.txt` from the archive `test.zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding escapes in a variable doesn't do anything, because the shell interprets quotes and escapes before it expands variables (i.e. by the time the escape's there, it's too late for it to do any good). Instead, put variable references in double-quotes to prevent the shell from interpreting spaces as word breaks. I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
for file in *.cbz
do
  zip -sf "$file" | grep banner | { while read p; do  zip -d "$file" "$p" ; done }
done
```

(Note that I also removed the `sed` command, since `read` trims leading and trailing whitespace.)

Comment: So it means we can break the thing by having files that start or end with whitespaces! Yeah! let's hack the thing down `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yep. If that's a concern (and the output format is predictable enough; not sure about that), use `IFS= read ...` and either `sed` or post-processing on `$p` to remove the spaces that aren't part of the filename. 'Course, it'll still break if there are linefeeds in the names...

Comment: works like a charm! I still don't understand how the shell does interpret spaces as word breaks in some cases and not in others, but i'm happy with the results. :D